# Python Regex Variable Negative Lookbehind

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation

I am trying to find the occurrence of various terms that are not preceded by another group of terms. Normally if I would have a single term in the preceding group I could use a negative lookbehind, but at Python has a zero-width assumption this doesn't seem to be the case. The only solution I see is to run two regexes, one for the presence of what I am looking for and another to confirm the non-existence of the preceding group terms. There must be a more elegant and efficient way of doing this. Can anyone help?

The test sentence is:

```
10 day trip excludes flights
```

The regex that assures that it isn't matched due to the word 'flights' being preceded by 'excludes' is the following:

```
(?:without|not including|doesn\'?t include|exclud(?:es|ing))\s*(?:flights?(?:\s+tickets)?|airfare|airline tickets?)
```

However I want to assure that certain text is included. I can confirm this with the following:

```
(?:flights?(?:\s+tickets)?|airfare|airline tickets?)
```

So this would match '*including ticket*' and '*and airfare*' but not '*without flight tickets*'

Some examples of matching strings are:

```
including flights
includes flights
plus flights
flights are included
including airfare
and airfare
```

Some examples of non-matching strings are:

```
not including flights
flights are not included
excluding flights
without airfare
```

Comment: post some examples for matching and non matching strings.

Comment: I've added some matching and non-matching strings

Comment: you mean this http://regex101.com/r/kA0mL3/1 ?

Comment: That's the base. However that matches anything not preceded by those particular terms. You can see an example here: http://regex101.com/r/kA0mL3/4

Comment: How about this http://regex101.com/r/kA0mL3/5 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the below regex,

```
^(?=.*?(?:flights|airfare))(?:(?!without|not includ(?:ing|ed)|doesn\'?t include|exclud(?:es|ing)).)*$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/kA0mL3/6)

Comment: That's awesome, I didn't think of using a look forward.